# SQL statement with if else

Tags: sql, if-statement

I want the output of SQL statement based on some if else condition.

For Ex:

```
select salary from EMP
```

EMP table has a column DOJ.

Now I want the output as '-' if the DOJ is less than 90 days.

How can i do this ?

Comment: `CASE` is your friend

Comment: Thanks friend. I hope this will work with multiple columns in result as well.

Comment: I am using SQL server

Comment: What datatype is DOJ? Is it a date and do you want to test 90 days from now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(DAY,DOJ,getdate()) < 90) then '-' else cast(Salary as varchar(15)) end as Salary
FROM EMP
```

Answer (score 2):

In sql-server

```
 select *,case when DATEDIFF(DAY,DOJ,getdate()) <=90 then '-' else null end as mytest
    from tbale
```

Answer (score 0):

For most of database servers you should use CASE but MySQL offers a shortcut:

```
SELECT IF(DOJ<90, '-', salary) FROM EMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select IIF ( DOJ < 90 , '-', salary ) as FormattedSalary
from EMP
```

Comment: You might have to cast salary as text, I don't know the format of that column of course.